# How to redirect different users to different activites?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: database]

This is my database structure, and I want users to be redirected to their respective activities based on their TYPE. I don't know the logic or syntax.
For someone reasons nothing seems to work.

```
   mAuthListener= new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
                startActivity(new Intent(login.this, MainActivity.class));
            }
        } };

    cardView1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startsignin();

        }
    });
        }

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
                         }

    private void startsignin()
    {
        String email = editText.getText().toString();
        String password = editText2.getText().toString();
   if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email) || TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){
       Toast.makeText(login.this,"Some fields are empty",        
       Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }
  else

      {                                                                                                     mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
          @Override
          public void onComplete(Task<AuthResult> task) {
              if (!task.isSuccessful())
              {
                  Toast.makeText(login.this,"Sign in failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              }

          }
      });


         }
    }
```

Comment: avoid exposing your firebase url, it can lead anyone with the link to make changes in your database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this, I recommend you to use the following lines of code:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference uidRef = rootRef.child("STUDENTS").child(uid);
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if(dataSnapshot.exists()) {
            //start students activity
        } else {
            //start teachers activity
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage());
    }
};
uidRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

Comment: First of all thank you for the input and no i have not tried it out yet. I have not been able to find time. I will update you once i do. Have a nice day/night.

Comment: Ok, keep me posted.

Comment: There is some problem with the line "String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();"   App crashes as soon as it is lunched.

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question.

Comment: OK so here's an update. The code you wrote, its working perfectly, there's nothing wrong with it. Android studio was giving me NullPointerException. So i did a little tweaking and wrapped the code you gave into a AuthStateListener. That somehow did the trick. You have no idea what you have done for me. However there is one more thing i need your help with. What if i had 3 users. STUDENTS, TEACHERS, ADMIN. so admin will be redirected to a third activity. How would you modify the code for a third user ? So far its working fine for two users. Whenever you are free, help me figure it out. Thanks

Comment: Good to hear that it worked :) This sounds as a new issue which basically should be considered another question that I cannot responde in a comment or using only the the data above. In order to follow the rules of this comunity, please post another fresh question using a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so me and other users can help you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52895188/how-to-redirect-multiple-types-of-users-to-their-respective-activities Alex please help.

Comment: @ConfusedANDHungry01 Ok, I'll take a look and if I'll know the answer, I'll write it to you.