# How to redirect multiple types of users to their respective Activities?

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-authentication

I am creating a voting app on Firebase. I have 3 types of users. So far i can successfully redirect 2 kinds of users (STUDENTS, TEACHERS) to their respective activities after they login all with the code below, [MY Users so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGhtM.png)
But now i have to add another user (ADMIN) and like other users, admin too should be redirected to their own specific activity after login. I am confused as to how to modify my code for a third user.

```
mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
            if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {

                String uid = mAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
                DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
                uidRef = rootRef.child("STUDENTS").child(uid);

                ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                            //start students activity
                            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, student.class));

                        } else {
                            //start teachers activity
                            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, teacher.class));
                        }
                    }

                    //
                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) 
                    {
                    }
                };


uidRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);

            }
            else{
                Log.d("TAG", "firebaseUser is null");
            }


        }
    };
```

Comment: Have you tried to do in the same way you did for student and teacher?

Comment: The IF Else condition is very well working for STUDENT& TEACHER. I know the code is ok but don't know how to modify it further for the third user. Thanks for responding Alex.

Comment: Have you tried to use a switch statement?

Comment: What exactly will be the condition for it? could you explain please.

Comment: Have you solved the problem?

Comment: I haven't used a switch statement, I have used in my answer an `if - else if` statement to see the solution more clearly. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using onlye `if (dataSnapshot.exists())` will not solve your 3 types of user problem. Assuming that the type of the third user is `3`, a change in your database structure is needed. So your new database schema should look like this:

```
Firebase-root
    |
    --- users
          |
          --- uidOne
          |     |
          |     --- name: "Ed"
          |     |
          |     --- type: 1
          |
          --- uidTwo
          |     |
          |     --- name: "Tyff"
          |     |
          |     --- type: 2
          |
          --- uidOne
                |
                --- name: "Admin"
                |
                --- type: 3
```

Now you shoud add a listener on the `uid` node and check the type of the user like this:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference uidRef = rootRef.child("users").child(uid);
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if(dataSnapshot.child("Type").getValue(Long.class) == 1) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, student.class));
        } else if (dataSnapshot.child("TYPE").getValue(Long.class) == 2) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, teacher.class));
        } else if (dataSnapshot.child("TYPE").getValue(Long.class) == 3) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, admin.class));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage());
    }
};
uidRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will try it out soon.

Comment: Ok, keep me posted.

Comment: Alex, I am sorry. i have not even been able to open up my laptop due to busy schedule and some personal responsibilities. however i am completely free this weekend and first thing i plan to do is code what you wrote. Thank you. Take care of yourself.

Comment: error  at   if(dataSnapshot.child("TYPE") == 1). It says  "operator == cannot be applied to int".  I tried converting to long, string. then it says   "operator == cannot be applied to java.lang.string"

Comment: Alex, Alex, Alex you are a life saver. Literally. I did some minor changes to the code and now everything is working perfectly. Even better, now i can add as many type of users as i want. All thanks to you. Thanks for being there. So much.

Answer (score 0):

you need another data-structure, with `users` and `roles/admin`,  `roles/teacher`,  `roles/student` and then check which node has the key (also compatible with security rules).

as you have it, you could simply remove the `else` branch and query all three nodes.

Answer (score 0):

This is my final code using Kotlin and it is working perfectly.

```
mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(Email, Password).addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {



                    val uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid
                    val rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
                    val uidRef = rootRef.child("Users").child(uid)
                    val spin: String = userchioce.selectedItem.toString()
                val valueEventListener: ValueEventListener = object : ValueEventListener {
                    override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                        when {
                                dataSnapshot.child("users").getValue(String::class.java) == "Admin" -> {
                                    if (spin.equals("Admin")){
                                val intent = Intent(this@Login, Admin::class.java)
                                startActivity(intent)}
                                    else{
                                        Toast.makeText(this@Login, "Select Your User-Type", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                            .show()
                                    }
                            }

                            dataSnapshot.child("users").getValue(String::class.java) == "Lecturer" -> {
                                if (spin.equals("Lecturer")) {
                                    val intent = Intent(this@Login, Lecturer::class.java)
                                    startActivity(intent)
                                }else{
                                    Toast.makeText(this@Login, "Select Your User-Type", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                        .show()
                                }
                            }
                            dataSnapshot.child("users").getValue(String::class.java) == "Parent" -> {
                                if (spin.equals("Parent")) {
                                    val intent = Intent(this@Login, Parent::class.java)
                                    startActivity(intent)
                                }else{
                                    Toast.makeText(this@Login, "Select Your User-Type", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                        .show()
                                }
                            }
                            dataSnapshot.child("users").getValue(String::class.java) == "Student" -> {
                                if (spin.equals("Student")) {
                                    val intent = Intent(this@Login, Student::class.java)
                                    startActivity(intent)
                                }else{
                                    Toast.makeText(this@Login, "Select Your User-Type", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                        .show()
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
                        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.message)
                    }
                }
                uidRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener)
                    progressDialog.dismiss()
                }
```