# Login with two seprate users in firebase

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I created login page with firebase and i use firstore to store some info about the users like ID.
I created 2 types of users: Employer and Worker, When i register as employer, i store custom ID in firestore with 8 letters from the UID of the user and i add in 'e' at first of the string. I do the same thing when Worker register but i add 'w' in at first of the string.

Now when i try login as employer i want to go to certain activity and if i login as worker i want to go to certain activity.

I dont know how to do this,I'd be happy to get help.
[image]

Comment: Check **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52895188/how-to-redirect-multiple-types-of-users-to-their-respective-activities)** out. Is for Firebase realtime database but same principle apply to Cloud Firestore. So change your database structure a little bit to have only one collection because Firestore cannot allow you query the database across different collections.

Answer (score 1):

The main launch activity can start another activity after login is complete. Edit whereever you want to do the transmission depending on the UID which in this case is either employer or worker. In the end you should be looking into something like this: *(As you provide no code block to help out,

```
    UID = getUID()//your method
    Intent intent; //this is the intent you will start
    if(UID == employee)//you can use first char to decide here
    {
        intent = new Intent(this, employer_activity.class);
        startActivity(intent);//this will start that activity as employer
    }
    else if(UID == worker)
    {
        intent = new Intent(this, worker_activity.class);
        startActivity(intent);//this will start that activity as worker
    }
```

Comment: This code will not work, because  if i do " UID = getUID()" I dont know if its UID of worker or employer.

Comment: @matan you send a query to fetch that UID person's information table. and from that table get the ID so that the first character of the ID you get will tell you if it is E or W in the end. (or get ID_intent directly from UID to skip the second part)