# How can I prevent Firebase user from logging into wrong login Screen

Tags: java, android, firebase

**Context**: In my Firebase Database I have a Parent called "Clients" that stores data in "Vendor" or "Eater" depending on which the client registered as.

**Issue:** Registered "Vendor" can login as "Eater" and "Eater" can login as "Vendor".  With Current code, app still allows "Vendor" to login the "Eater" screen and vice versa.

**What I need to do:** Only allow "Vendor" to login the Vendor screen and "Eater" in the Eater screen.

**Errors:** I get this crash when either an Eater or Vendor Logins to the Eater screen on the

@Overridepublic void onDataChange

*"java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.Object.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference at com.example.zzyzj.eloteroman.login.EatCornLoginActivity$4.onDataChange"*

```
    loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            circProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            final String emailUser = emailEditText.getText().toString();
            final String passwordUser = passwordEditText.getText().toString();

            firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(emailUser, passwordUser).addOnCompleteListener(EatCornLoginActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()){
                        circProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    } else {
                        checkIfUserIsEaterOrVendor();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
}  


   public void checkIfUserIsEaterOrVendor(){
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().
            child("Clients").
            child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).
            child("Eater").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.getValue().equals("Eater")) {
                //Code if the user is Eater
                circProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                Toast.makeText(EatCornLoginActivity.this, R.string.login_success_toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                startActivity(new Intent(EatCornLoginActivity.this, MapsActivity.class));
            } else {
                //Code if the user is Vendor trying to login as Eater
                circProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                Toast.makeText(EatCornLoginActivity.this, R.string.login_failed_toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), databaseError.getMessage(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I am not proper understand what you want?

Comment: **[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52961209/5246885)** might help you.

Comment: updated the code and question layout

Comment: When you say, the Vendor can login as Eater and Eater can login as Vendor, is there a switch on the login screen for the user to select the flow or you are showing the appropriate flow based on the credentials?

Comment: `dataSnapshot.getValue()` is null and because of it null pointer exception is thrown. So, check for nulls before comapring it with Eater String

Comment: When the user opens the App they are given to button options; one to be a Vendor and another to be an Eater.  If they Click Vendor they go to the Vendor Registration/Login Screen.  Then when they log in they are sent to the VendorMaps Activity.  Same for Eater except they are sent to the Eater Maps Activity.

Comment: So something like `if (dataSnapshot.getValue() == null) {
                               dataSnapshot.getValue().equals("Eater")` ?

Comment: Small change, something like `if (dataSnapshot.getValue() != null) { dataSnapshot.getValue().equals("Eater")`

Comment: I can't wait to try this, I must get sleep now I will keep you updated, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use SharedPreferences.So you can store a userid with value of what type of user is register and check login if userid is match as your value so,it can login if you want.

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("com.example.pc.it7project.data", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putString(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid(), "Vendor");
editor.apply();
```

And you get value of shared preference using this code

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("com.example.pc.it7project.data", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String sc = sharedPref.getString(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid(), "");
```

And check

```
if(sc.equals("Vendor"))
{
//Put Your Code Here
}
```

I hope this can help you!

Thank You.

Comment: This looks promising.  I wonder, is there a way to get the name of the child that the UID is stored in and pass that as a reference to check if the user UID matches with the child that the UID is stored in?  I am thinking of this in order to prevent any bugs in the future if a user uninstalls the app or installs it on a new phone.

Answer (score 1):

**For registration:**

> You should ask user first, either user want to register as vendor or eater. Once
>   user registered itself then save its type into firebase database.

**e-g bleow:**

> registered_user:
>   +user_key:(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
>   +user_type:vendor/eater (under user_key node)

**For login:**

> You must have two button to differentiate login e-g login as vendor or
>   login as eater. e-g If user click on login as vendor then pass its
>   type through intent to login activiy.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(StartScreen.this,LoginActivity.class); 
intent.putExtra("user_type","vendor"); 
startActivity(intent);
```

Once authenticated the user then check its type

```
                if (!task.isSuccessful() && client_db ){
                    circProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    Toast.makeText(EatCornLoginActivity.this, R.string.login_failed_toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    circProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    Toast.makeText(EatCornLoginActivity.this, R.string.login_success_toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    // If Login/Registration Successful send user to MapsActivity
         checkUserValidation 


                }
```

> getIntent().getStringExtra("user_type"), will give the type which you
>   passed from StratScreen.this so If you its user_type exists then you
>   will pass to next activity otherwise show an error toast

```
public void checkUserValidation(){
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("registered_user").
            child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).child(getIntent().getStringExtra("user_type")).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.getValue() != null) {
                startActivity(new Intent(EatCornLoginActivity.this, MapsActivity.class));
            }else{
        Log.e("notify","Error in login");
    }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

**PS:**

> If you want to user SharePreferences then It's easy to do but one
>   problem may arise If user clear cache or uninstall then reinstall the
>   application the application would not be able to find the
>   Sharepreferences file. Sharepreferences stores data in local file.

Comment: Great layout for help.  I am going with not using shared pref because of your advice.  I updated my post and I am almost complete but I still run into an error and crash.

Answer (score 1):

I think a good way of solving this problem would be adding a new field in your Firebase database for every user indicating if it is a Vendor or Eater. This field can be populated when creating an account. Next, when someone wants to login you should first check if it is a Vendor trying to login on Vendor screen or Eater screen and vice versa. That way you will know for sure the type of the user. Can you do this with your implementation or I am missing something?

Example function:

```
    public void checkUserType(){
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().
                child("Users").
                child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).
                child("user_type").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.getValue().equals("Vendor")) {
                    //Code if the user is Vendor depending on the screen
                } else {
                    //Code if the user is Eater depending on the screen
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                log.e(databaseError);
            }
        });
     }
```

Comment: Please consider posting this answer as a comment or try adding some code in the answer.

Comment: This looks really clean.  I like this.  I would then store the intent to log the user in the statement  if (dataSnapshot.getValue().equals("Vendor")) correct?

Comment: Check out my updated post, I used some of this code but I still get a crash error.  Almost there

Comment: I think that the null pointer is because you don't have Eater value in the database. 
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().
            child("Clients").
            child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).
            child("Eater").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
will return the value of Eater. I suggest adding category field instead of Eater in Firebase and in that field add Eater as String if the user is Eater and Vendor if the user is Vendor, that way you will distinguish the users and be able to compare with .equals.().

Comment: You can do the same with boolean, for example true - Eater, false -  Vendor, but you will have to change the dataSnapshot.getValue().equals("Vendor") part to dataSnapshot.getValue() == true, or just dataSnapshot.getValue().

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  The weird thing is, I do have Eater value in Database.  

This is how I create the user when they register as an Eater:

String client_id = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                            DatabaseReference client_db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Clients").child("Eater").child(client_id);
                            client_db.setValue(true);

Comment: Ow, maybe you should consider changing the database, because with this approach it will be very difficult to find which user is Eater or Vendor.

Comment: I would for sure consider changing the database.  So right now the way it is, it creates a Clients child, and then if they register as a vendor it puts that data in a Vendor child within the Clients.  Same for Eater.  That's not the best way to do it?

Comment: For the flexibility that you need I would create Clients child and inside I would create users with 3 parameters: email, name, boolean (Vendor or Client). You can later add more if needed.

Answer (score 1):

You should first login and get the user id and then use that to query the eater reference then if that user exist go to the eater screen else go to the vendor screen

```
loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        circProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        final String emailUser = emailEditText.getText().toString();
        final String passwordUser = passwordEditText.getText().toString();

       firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(emailUser, passwordUser)
      .addOnCompleteListener(EatCornLoginActivity.this, new 
       OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
          @Override
          public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
              if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                  Log.d(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:success");
                  FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

                  DatabaseReference client_db = 
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Clients")
                .child("Eater")
                .child(user.getUid());

             client_db.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() 

             {

                 @Override
                 public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                   if (snapshot.exists()) {
                       // go to eater activity
                   }else{
                     //go to vendor activity
                    }

                 }

              @Override
             public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
             Toast.makeText(getContext(), firebaseError.getMessage(), 
             Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }
       });


    } else {
           // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
           Log.w(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:failure", 
           task.getException());
           Toast.makeText(EmailPasswordActivity.this, "Authentication 
                failed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

            // ...
        }
    });
```

Comment: This looks really good and easy to use.  What I am thinking I could do is if (snapshot.exists()) for the Vendor and they try to login with the vendor screen, it will work and log them in, if not it will have an error.  I'm going to try this.

Comment: I used this code and get an error, I updated the original post

Comment: your new code will crash if that user has no value in his  edit section. so you should first do a check if the snapshot is null