# App crashes when user logs out with Firebase while using Geofire

Tags: android, firebase, geofire

**Solved:**  "Check FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() != null before calling the getUid." – Srikar Reddy (in comments)

**Context:** my app is using Firebase and Geofire to get the user location and update it.  When the user is not on the Map Screen, it removes their Geofire location from Firebase Database.  It is a live tracking app. The app correctly tracks and updates the user.  Everything works fine.  Their Geofire data is removed from Firebase correctly.  Except, when I log out I run into issues.  Logging back in works just fine too.

**Issue:** when I log out, the app crashes with this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser.getUid()' on a null object reference
```

**What I have tried:**

```
  String vendorId = Objects.requireNonNull(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()).getUid();
```

But it also crashes with this error:

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to stop activity {com.example.zzyzj.eloteroman/com.example.zzyzj.eloteroman.VendorMapsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

**My code:**

```
 //Logout Menu Option Button
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        // If Logout Button is clicked within 2 Seconds log user out
        case R.id.logoutMenuOption:
            if (logoutAppPressAgain + 2000 > System.currentTimeMillis()) {
                logoutToast.cancel();

                // Remove VendorOnline Child before logging out to prevent crash
                removeVendorOnline();

                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                Intent logoutIntent = new Intent(VendorMapsActivity.this, WelcomeActivity.class);
                startActivity(logoutIntent);
                finish();
            } else {
                logoutToast = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), R.string.press_button_again_to_logout, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                logoutToast.show();
            }

            logoutAppPressAgain = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

 @Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    lastLocation = location;

    if (currentUserLocationMarker != null) {
        currentUserLocationMarker.remove();
    }

    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
    markerOptions.position(latLng);
    markerOptions.title(getString(R.string.user_current_location_marker_title));
    markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.corn_icon));

    currentUserLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

    float zoom = 17.0f;

    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, zoom));
    mMap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(false);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);

    // Adds VendorOnline Child to Firebase when Vendor is On This Activity
    addVendorOnline();

}

 @Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if (googleApiClient != null) {
        googleApiClient.connect();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    // When Vendor is not on this screen activity it will remove their data from Firebase
    removeVendorOnline();

    if (googleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        googleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
}

// When user swipe closes app it logs them out

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    removeVendorOnline();
    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
}

// Prevent user from going to unwanted Activities when back button is pressed, instead user logout

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (exitAppPressBack + 2000 > System.currentTimeMillis()) {
        exitAppBackToast.cancel();
        super.onBackPressed();

        // Remove VendorOnline Child before logging out to prevent crash
        removeVendorOnline();

        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
        Intent logoutIntent = new Intent(VendorMapsActivity.this, WelcomeActivity.class);
        startActivity(logoutIntent);
        finish();
    } else {
        exitAppBackToast = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), R.string.press_back_one_more_time_to_exit, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        exitAppBackToast.show();
    }

    exitAppPressBack = System.currentTimeMillis();
}


 // Code to store Vendor data when a Vendor is Online in Firebase
// Creates new Child within Firebase Database "VendorsOnline" when a Vendor is Online
// Uses Geofire to update location and update Vendor Online Data in Firebase

public void addVendorOnline(){

    String vendorId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
    DatabaseReference vendorIdReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("VendorOnline");
    GeoFire vendorGeoFire = new GeoFire(vendorIdReference);
    vendorGeoFire.setLocation(vendorId, new GeoLocation(lastLocation.getLatitude(), lastLocation.getLongitude()));
}

// Removes Vendor from VendorOnline Child in Firebase

public void removeVendorOnline() {

    String vendorId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
    DatabaseReference vendorIdReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("VendorOnline");
    GeoFire vendorGeoFire = new GeoFire(vendorIdReference);
    vendorGeoFire.removeLocation(vendorId);
}
```

Comment: Activity lifecycles is the issue, your code is requesting the `getUid` after logout.

Comment: Check `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() != null` before calling the `getUid`.

Comment: Why is there `removeVendorOnline` in `onStop` and `onDestroy`?

Comment: You're a life saver!  It works now!  Thank you!  Spent around 3 hours on this.  Earlier I was using `if (FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid() != null)`  - I had the right idea I just needed to remove the .`getUid()` like you have!  Awesome!   

`onStop` so when the user is not on the screen it stops tracking them and removes their Geofire location from the Firebase Database.  Actually, it was to be safe but I just realized it was redundant with `onDestroy`.  I just tested it and found out I didn't need it so I just removed it right now.

Comment: I wish I could mark this post as answered by you but I don't think I can if the answer is in a comment and not a post.  Thanks again.  Would really appreciate your tips and advice on my other Firebase post that I have been trying to figure out:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55157080/how-can-i-prevent-firebase-user-from-logging-into-wrong-login-screen

Comment: Please respect the customs of Stack Overflow and post the solution as an answer, that you then accept. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31809/putting-solved-in-the-title-of-a-question