# Redirect the user to their profile or activity?

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I used the radio group button to signup user like if the user is student then he register as student ,if user is teacher is then select the teacher radio button and sign up and i want that when user login he redirect to their related activity or profile and i'm using firebase realtime database

Comment: You should save the selected value (student/teacher) in a persistent storage (shared preferences for example) and use this value later to decide which intent you'll start after successful login

Comment: can you help with the shared preferences code?

Comment: mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,pass).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                if(task.isSuccessful()){



                    Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this, StudentTariningFargment.class);

                    startActivity(in);
                  //  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"wellcome"+email, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                else{

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"error",

Comment: Check **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52895188/how-to-redirect-multiple-types-of-users-to-their-respective-activities)** out.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to redirect the user every time, he uses your application, you should save the selected option using e.g. preferences. [Here do you see, how to save and load them.](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences)

You can redirect the user/start an activity using Intents. [Here do you see, how to start other Intents.](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity)

Comment: every user login goes to same activity and i want to change that for two or three users only that each one of them go to diiferent activity

Comment: Then you have to identify these users somehow (e.g. by using the mentioned `Preferences`) and redirect them using the mentioned `Intents`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this in your activity:

```
enum UserType {STUDENT, TEACHER, STAFF}

    static final String PREF_KEY_USER_TYPE = "USER_TYPE";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Set pref based on user type
        if (condition) {
            setUserType(UserType.STUDENT);
        } else {
            setUserType(UserType.TEACHER);
        }

    }

    private SharedPreferences getSharedPref() {
        return getSharedPreferences("user_type_pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    private void setUserType(UserType userType) {
        getSharedPref().edit().putString(PREF_KEY_USER_TYPE, userType.name()).apply();
    }

    private String getUserType() {
        return getSharedPref().getString(PREF_KEY_USER_TYPE, "");
    }
```