# Android: Is there any way to add multiple intents in single onItemClickListner() method in custom listview?

Tags: android, firebase, listview, android-intent

I've one listview that has to be accessed by two different type users and open two different activities ie.

if user type 1 clicks the item in list view, activity A opens. 
 if user type 2 clicks on the item in listview, activity B opens.

The following code is what i need to get fixed. Note that the users reside in firebase.

```
 mylistview.setOnItemClickListener(newAdapterView.OnItemClickListen() 
{
@Override   
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, 
long id)           
{ 
//call activity A when clicked by user type 1
Intent i=new Intent(this,ActivityA.class);
startActivity(i);


//call activty B when clicked by user type 2
Intent i=new Intent(this,ActivityB.class);
startActivity(i);
}
```

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking for.

Comment: Check **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52895188/how-to-redirect-multiple-types-of-users-to-their-respective-activities)** out.

Answer (score 0):

You have to start the activity, based on the user's status:

```
 mylistview.setOnItemClickListener(newAdapterView.OnItemClickListen() 
{
@Override   
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, 
long id)           
{
Intent i;
if (userIsAdmin()) { 
  //call delete dialogue box when clicked by admin
  i=new Intent(this,ActivityA.class);
} else {

   //call edit dialogue box when clicked by customer
   i=new Intent(this,ActivityB.class);
}

startActivity(i);
```

Note also, that an `Activity` is not a `Dialog`, so your comment can be confusing to others.