# Role Based Auto Login in Android Studio

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I'm creating a app in which 5 different users are available FOUR are WORKERS and ONE is CLIENT. All users are able to login in app using their email and password, but i want that 4 users from those 5 are redirect to one activity and remaining one user redirect to another different activity, Which is working fine, but at time time of auto-login i want the same thing will happen but whenever i logged in as WORKER and then clear the app from memory, and at the time of auto-login the CLIENT is logged in every time.

At the time of registration every users have to select their designation and the client designation will remain EMPTY every time now trying to let users auto-login based on their designation Which i used as USER TYPE.

[image]

I want at time auto-login FOUR USERS(WORKERS) redirect to different one activity and the ONE user which is CLIENT redirect to another different activity. What i have to user for this, which method is better for me?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow ! Could you show us what you have tried so far, in terms of code ?

Comment: I have tried this kind of methods and logics alot. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52895188/how-to-redirect-multiple-types-of-users-to-their-respective-activities

Comment: And why is this not doing what you want ?

Comment: are you using firebase authentication ?

Comment: Have you solve your problem?

Comment: no stiil stuck in that error @Ticherhaz

Comment: Yes Sir..@bugfreerammohan

Comment: **And why is this not doing what you want ?**

Comment: I don't know i have already used many codes and methods but i doesn't get any solutions for that problem, if you can help me than please.. its really urgent. @ArthurAttout

Comment: The question you linked has **exactly** the same statement, and the accepted answer fulfills it. Please edit your question to specify why this answer didn't work, what error you have instead, what you expected to have, and what you have tried to solve the problem.

Comment: Answering 'I don't know' to the question 'Why isn't this solution doing what you want' is an indication that you're a bit lost with what you are doing, and you should start with a less complicated problem, and go on step-by-step.

Comment: i Want to know that the question i have linked, is it the right why for auto-login according to my problem @ArthurAttout

Comment: Does the original question reflects your situation ? If so, then yes.

Comment: no it doesn't, the original question is only about login but, in my situation its about auto-login.

Comment: did you create your account while you already logged in? @ShubhamChauhan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Have user Session To Save Current Login User-Type, and it is working great.

Here is my session code:-

```
private SharedPreferences prefs;
private static AppSession session;

public static AppSession getInstance(Context cntx) {
    if (session == null)
        session = new AppSession(cntx);
    return session;
}

public AppSession(Context cntx) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(cntx);
}


public void setHasLoging(boolean value) {
    prefs.edit().putBoolean("hasLoging", value).commit();
}

public void setUserHasLoging(boolean value){
    prefs.edit().putBoolean("UserHasLoging", value).commit();
}

public boolean getHasLoging() {
    return prefs.getBoolean("hasLoging", false);
}

public boolean getUserHasLoging(){
    return prefs.getBoolean("UserHasLoging", false);
}



public void clear() {

    prefs.edit().clear().commit();
}
```

Login Activity Code:-

```
        userDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(RegisteredUserID);

        userDatabaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {


            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                String userType = dataSnapshot.child("designation").getValue().toString();

                if (userType.equals("CA")){
                    mAppSession.setHasLoging(true);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }

                else if (userType.equals("CLIENT")){
                    mAppSession.setUserHasLoging(true);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, DashBoardActivity.class);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }

                else if (userType.equals("ADVOCATE")){
                    mAppSession.setHasLoging(true);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }

                else if (userType.equals("CMA")){
                    mAppSession.setHasLoging(true);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }

                else if (userType.equals("CS")){
                    mAppSession.setHasLoging(true);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    } else {
        SweetToast.info(LoginActivity.this, "Email is not verified. Please verify first");
        mAuth.signOut();
    }
}













Here Splash Screen I used as Launcher Activity to check the condition which user is logged in.

AppSession mSession;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference;



@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

    if (user == null){

        Intent intent =  new Intent(SplashActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

    else if (user != null){

        mDatabaseReference.child(user.getUid()).child("online").setValue(ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
    mSession = AppSession.getInstance(this);
    rightAction();




}

private void rightAction(){

    if (mSession.getHasLoging()) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

   else if (mSession.getUserHasLoging()){
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, DashBoardActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent1);
        finish();

    }
```