# Finding a user data based on email

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i have gotten the email of a user in LoginPage, now i want to get his data (the users data include: mobile number ,name,bday date and most importantly type(business/regular)), based on the type i can know where should i redirect the user (if the user's type is business then ill send hime to the BusinessHomeActivity..)
you can see my database structure (each UID contains email,bday,type,mpbile number) which is the user's info
i hope you can help me
(Java,android studio)
thank you!

[image]

Comment: I think, this **[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52895188/how-to-redirect-multiple-types-of-users-to-their-respective-activities)** might help.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple you can get this UID like this

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(getActivity(), task -> {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                   // here you get the logged-in user UID if login successful
                   String userUID = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()
                   // set the path of your database and get the UID from it
                   String path = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("yourRootKey").child("User").child(userUID).child("Email")

                   //add a listener to get value
                   path.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            // here you can get value from dataSnapshot as above you can achieve from onDataChange and check the type
                            // and navigate to user
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                           Log.e("onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
                        }
                   });
                    
                } else {
                    // login failed display as toast
                }
            });
```