# Trying to send Users to different Activities depending on type. keep getting Operator cannot be applied to database reference and String

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

This is my code in my login activity

I keep getting the **Operator == cannot be applied to Database reference and String**, am I doing something wrong. I am trying to get users to different activities depending on their type="1","2","3". But, keep getting this problem that is highlighted in bold. Can someone help me fix it.

I am a complete newbie at all this both firebase and kotlin.

```
private fun performLogin() {
        val email = email_edittext_login.text.toString()
        val password = password_edittext_login.text.toString()
        val uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().uid

        if (email.isEmpty() || password.isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter your email/password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            return
        }
        Log.d("LoginActivity", "Attempt login with email/pw: $email/xxx")
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener {
                    if (!it.isSuccessful) return@addOnCompleteListener

                    Log.d("Login", "User successfully logged in: ${it.result!!.user!!.uid} $email")
                    if(ref.child("users").child("type") == "1"){
                        val intent = Intent(this, DashBoardActivity::class.java)
                        intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK.or(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
                        startActivity(intent)
                    }else if(ref.child("users").child("type") == "2"){
                        val intent = Intent(this, DashBoardActivity::class.java)
                        intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK.or(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
                        startActivity(intent)
                    }else if(ref.child("users").child("type") == "3"){
                        val intent = Intent(this, DashBoardActivity::class.java)
                        intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK.or(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
                        startActivity(intent)
                    }
                    
                    
                
                }
```

Here are my register activity code and My user class and the data that gets saved into the firebase database

```
private fun saveToFirebaseDatabase(){
        val uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().uid ?: ""
        val ref =  FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/users/$uid")

        val user =  User(uid,
                    Fname_edittext_register.text.toString(),
                    Lname_edittext_register.text.toString(),
                    mobile_edittext_register.text.toString(),
                    dob_edittext_register.text.toString(),
                    email_edittext_register.text.toString(),
                    type = "1"
                    )

        ref.setValue(user)
            .addOnSuccessListener {
                Log.d("Register","user information saved into firebase database")
                val intent = Intent(this, DashBoardActivity::class.java)
                intent.flags=Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK.or(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
                startActivity(intent)
            }
            .addOnFailureListener(){
                Log.d("Tag", "failed to set value to database: ${it.message}")
            }


    }

`
   class User(val uid: String,
           val Firstname:String,
           val Lastname:String,
           val Mobile:String,
           val Dateofbirth:String,
           val email:String,
           val type: String
){
    constructor() : this("", "", "","","","", "")
}`
```

Comment: What is `ref`? .

Comment: val ref =  FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/users/$uid") it is further above the loginActivity

Comment: You have to read the value of the database object at the address specified by the DatabaseReference to be able to compare its value to something else. I don't use Firebase so don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the following error:

> Operator == cannot be applied to Database reference and String

Because you are trying to compare two totally different types of objects:

```
ref.child("users").child("type") == "1"
```

The object on the left-hand side is an object of type DatabaseReference, while on the right-hand side is a String. These objects will never be equal. If you want to compare the value of the "type" property from the database with "1", then you should attach a listener and read that particular value, and right after that do the comparison, as explained in my answer from the following post:

> [How to redirect multiple types of users to their respective Activities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52895188/how-to-redirect-multiple-types-of-users-to-their-respective-activities)

Comment: I can't find anything on how to use the ValueEventListener. I've tried understanding what you have done, I'm just not understanding how to do it in kotlin

Comment: Have you tried to simply copy and paste that Java code in Android Studio? It will be converted automatically in Kotlin code.

Comment: You've gotta be kidding me

Comment: @Bilaldar I'm not. You can copy Java code and paste it into a Kotlin project, and it will be converted automatically for you. Have you tried?

Comment: Okay, I've done it fixed it to my Application, but the uidRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener is having problems

Comment: "is having problems" doesn't explain much. If you run into other issues, it's best to post a new question using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you.

Comment: Hey alex, thank you very much. I was finally able to get it to work thank a lot your the best. I apologize for any inconveniences i may have caused. Thank you again