# I'm using phone number to to sign in user in firebase android ,how can i keep user signed in until user sign out?

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

Code of my splash screen:

```
public class SplashScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);
        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
        Thread thread = new Thread() {

            public void run() {
                try {
                    sleep(5000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, FirstSlider.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();

                }
            }
        };
        thread.start();
    }
}
```

I want to move directly to my mainActivity if user already exist.

Comment: there is no error in the code but i want to know how can i stay an user logged in

Comment: The user stays logged in until you are explicitly sign out. Do you get some other behavior? I think you mi might be interested in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52895188/how-to-redirect-multiple-types-of-users-to-their-respective-activities).

Answer (score 0):

> I'm using phone number to to sign in user in firebase android ,how can i keep user signed in until user sign out?

This is actually the default behavior of Firebase Authentication: it persists the user credentials and restores them when the app restarts.

So by the time your main activity executes the `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()` should already be returning the restored user account. If that is not happening, consider [listening to the authentication state](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/google-cloud/articles/68104924/listen-for-authentication-state-in-android) to ensure your code executes after the user is restored.

If neither of these is working for you, edit your question to show the **relevant** code - as none of the code you shared now seems to call Firebase in any way.